How to register listener using WorkflowStatusListener interface of OSS/Netflix Conductor
Custom listener registration for Netflix Conductor to trigger upon workflow completion but not functioning as expected.
How can I register a custom listener in my code that should trigger when Netflix Conductor finishes executing a workflow? It seems that the listener is not being invoked upon workflow completion, even though I have set workflowStatusListenerEnabled to true. Am i missing anything?
Below is the code for my Custom Listener :
import com.netflix.conductor.common.run.Workflow;
import com.netflix.conductor.common.run.Workflow.WorkflowStatus;
import com.netflix.conductor.core.listener.WorkflowStatusListener;
import com.netflix.conductor.model.WorkflowModel;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyWorkflowStatusListener implements WorkflowStatusListener {

    @Override
    public void onWorkflowCompleted(WorkflowModel workflow) {
        System.out.println("Completed" + workflow);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWorkflowTerminated(WorkflowModel workflow) {
        System.out.println("Terminated" + workflow);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWorkflowFinalized(WorkflowModel workflow) {
        System.out.println("finalized" + workflow);
    }
}


